# MySQL AND statement in Case Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause, case-statement

I am super new to SQL so my apologies if I'm doing everything wrong, but is there any way I could modify this code

```
    select e.*,
    sum(case when (o.svcdate_form >= e.pre_date AND o.svcdate_form < e.svcdate_form AND (o.dx1 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4) OR o.dx2 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4)
        OR o.dx3 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4))) then pay else 0 end) as pre_pay,
    sum(case when (o.svcdate_form > e.svcdate_form AND o.svcdate_form <= e.post_date AND (o.dx1 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4) OR o.dx2 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4)
        OR o.dx3 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4))) then pay else 0 end) as post_pay,
    sum(case when (o.svcdate_form >= e.pre_date AND o.svcdate_form <= e.post_date AND (o.dx1 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4) OR o.dx2 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4)
        OR o.dx3 IN(e.dx1, e.dx2, e.dx3,e.dx4))) then o.pay else 0 end) as total_pay
from eoc_dx_lookup_member_wide_new e
left join ccaeo190_ky o 
    on  o.enrolid = e.enrolid
    and (
        e.dx1 in (o.dx1, o.dx2, o.dx3) 
        or e.dx2 in (o.dx1, o.dx2, o.dx3)
        or e.dx3 in (o.dx1, o.dx2, o.dx3)
        or e.dx4 in (o.dx1, o.dx2, o.dx3)
    )
group by e.svcdate_form;
```

Or at least have a code that would give me a similar result to what I am trying to do? I have multiple conditions for my case statements and don't know if this is possible.
Thanks in advance!

"*eoc_dx_lookup_member_wide_new e*" table looks like so:

```
enrolid | msclmid | svcdate_form | proc2 | pre_date   | post_date  | dx1   | dx2    | dx3    | dx4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    | 22      | 2019-03-18   | 20600 | 2019-03-08 | 2019-03-28 | M2021 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
1234    | 23      | 2019-05-08   | 28291 | 2019-02-07 | 2019-08-06 | M2021 | M21611 | M25571 | NULL
1234    | 20610   | 2019-09-19   | 20680 | 2019-09-09 | 2019-09-29 | Z4789 | M21611 | M65871 | M1990
```

My "*ccaeo190_ky o*" table looks something like this:

```
enrolid | msclmid | svcdate_form | proc1 | dx1   | dx2    | dx3    | pay
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    | 45      | 2019-03-10   | 20600 | M2021 | NULL   | NULL   | 45
1234    | 47      | 2019-03-26   | 74987 | NULL  | NULL   | M2021  | 62
1234    | 24      | 2019-06-20   | 34567 | M2021 | M21611 | M25571 | 123
1234    | 78      | 2019-05-08   | 27459 | NULL  | NULL   | M2021  | 62
1234    | 60      | 2019-09-19   | 97860 | M1990 | NULL   | NULL   | 54
```

what I'm hoping to achieve would be an output like this:

```
enrolid | msclmid | svcdate_form | proc2 | pre_date   | post_date  | dx1   | dx2    | dx3    | dx4   | pre_pay | post_pay | total_pay
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1234    | 22      | 2019-03-18   | 20600 | 2019-03-08 | 2019-03-28 | M2021 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL  | 45      | 62       | 107
1234    | 23      | 2019-05-08   | 28291 | 2019-02-07 | 2019-08-06 | M2021 | M21611 | M25571 | NULL  | 0       | 123      | 185
1234    | 20610   | 2019-09-19   | 20680 | 2019-09-09 | 2019-09-29 | Z4789 | M21611 | M65871 | M1990 | 0       | 0        | 54
```

I want to sum the pay column in the o table **only if** they fall within the pre_date and post_date window *and* contain any of the dx codes for a specific row in my mapping table

Comment: (1) The query is not complete (2) You are still to tell what you want to do (3) Sample data and desired results would also help clarifying your question.

Comment: Your question itself is not complete.

Comment: I've modified my question to include my entire query as well as examples of what I am working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```
CREATE TABLE test.a (
enrolid INT
, msclmid INT
, svcdate_form DATE
, proc2 INT
, pre_date DATE
, post_date DATE
, dx1 VARCHAR(50)
, dx2 VARCHAR(50)
, dx3 VARCHAR(50)
, dx4 VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE test.b (
enrolid INT
, msclmid INT
, svcdate_form DATE
, proc1 INT
, dx1 VARCHAR(50)
, dx2 VARCHAR(50)
, dx3 VARCHAR(50)
, pay INT
);

INSERT INTO test.a VALUES 
(1234,22,str_to_date('2019-03-18','%Y-%m-%d'),20600,str_to_date('2019-03-08','%Y-%m-%d'),str_to_date('2019-03-28','%Y-%m-%d'),'M2021',NULL,NULL,NULL),
(1234,23,str_to_date('2019-05-08','%Y-%m-%d'),28291,str_to_date('2019-02-07','%Y-%m-%d'),str_to_date('2019-08-06','%Y-%m-%d'),'M2021','M21611','M25571',NULL),
(1234,20610,str_to_date('2019-09-19','%Y-%m-%d'),20680,str_to_date('2019-09-09','%Y-%m-%d'),str_to_date('2019-09-29','%Y-%m-%d'),'Z4789','M21611','M65871','M1990');


INSERT INTO test.b VALUES 
(1234,45,str_to_date('2019-03-10','%Y-%m-%d'),20600,'M2021',NULL,NULL,45),
(1234,47,str_to_date('2019-03-26','%Y-%m-%d'),74987,NULL,NULL,'M2021',62),
(1234,24,str_to_date('2019-06-20','%Y-%m-%d'),34567,'M2021','M21611','M25571',123),
(1234,78,str_to_date('2019-05-08','%Y-%m-%d'),27459,NULL,NULL,'M2021',62),
(1234,60,str_to_date('2019-09-19','%Y-%m-%d'),97860,'M1990',NULL,NULL,54);
```

and the query:

```
SELECT e.enrolid 
, e.msclmid 
, e.svcdate_form
, e.proc2 
, e.pre_date 
, e.post_date 
, e.dx1 
, e.dx2
, e.dx3 
, e.dx4 
, sum(CASE 
    WHEN o.svcdate_form >= e.pre_date AND o.svcdate_form < e.svcdate_form THEN pay
    ELSE 0
  END) as pre_pay 
, sum(CASE
    WHEN o.svcdate_form > e.svcdate_form AND o.svcdate_form <= e.post_date THEN pay 
    ELSE 0
  END) as post_pay 
, sum(CASE
    WHEN o.svcdate_form >= e.pre_date AND o.svcdate_form <= e.post_date THEN pay 
    ELSE 0
  END) as total_pay
FROM test.a e
LEFT JOIN test.b o
ON e.enrolid = o.enrolid 
WHERE 1=1
AND CASE 
        WHEN e.dx1 = o.dx1 OR e.dx1 = o.dx2 OR e.dx1 = o.dx3 THEN 1
        WHEN e.dx2 = o.dx1 OR e.dx2 = o.dx2 OR e.dx2 = o.dx3 THEN 1
        WHEN e.dx3 = o.dx1 OR e.dx3 = o.dx2 OR e.dx3 = o.dx3 THEN 1
        WHEN e.dx4 = o.dx1 OR e.dx4 = o.dx2 OR e.dx4 = o.dx3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END = 1
GROUP BY e.enrolid 
, e.msclmid 
, e.svcdate_form
, e.proc2 
, e.pre_date 
, e.post_date 
, e.dx1 
, e.dx2
, e.dx3 
, e.dx4
;
```

tho, there is a little difference in one column/row .. I don't really get what exactly are your conditions.. anyway, this might be a good starting point for you

```
enrolid|msclmid|svcdate_form|proc2|pre_date  |post_date |dx1  |dx2   |dx3   |dx4  |pre_pay|post_pay|total_pay|
-------|-------|------------|-----|----------|----------|-----|------|------|-----|-------|--------|---------|
   1234|     22|  2019-03-18|20600|2019-03-08|2019-03-28|M2021|      |      |     |     45|      62|      107|
   1234|     23|  2019-05-08|28291|2019-02-07|2019-08-06|M2021|M21611|M25571|     |    107|     123|      292|
   1234|  20610|  2019-09-19|20680|2019-09-09|2019-09-29|Z4789|M21611|M65871|M1990|      0|       0|       54|
```